# How to map only when the field is not null in JOLT

Tags: jolt

Here is my input :

```
   { "isPoolPoint": "test", "timeZone": "ET" }
```

I want output to be :

```
   { "address" : [{"line2": "test"}] }
```

I should not get any thing as output if `isPoolPoint` is a `null`.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to *StackOverflow*. Please go through [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a question. Also, please provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that you have tried so far. Show some effort that you have put and I'm sure we'll be able to help you from there on.

Answer (score 2):

Spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "isPoolPoint": {
        // match down into the values of "isPoolPoint"
        // if we match null, then do nothing
        "null": null,
        // match everything else
        "*": {
          // write what was matched to the output
          "$": "address[0].line2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I wanted to ignore blank strings as well in addition to null values so I did below extra condition

[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "isPoolPoint": {
         // OR operator below will care of empty string or null
        "|null": null,
        "*": {
          "$": "address[0].line2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```